# json to std::string in c++ from an URL

Tags: c++, json

I want to implement something where I will get an URL which will be a link to JSON db, now I need to get the json from this URL and convert it to std:string in a c++ file. Is there any easy way to do this.

Comment: Please specify a platform. Windows comes with a built-in HTTP library (WinInet), on *nix there's libcurl and many others...

Answer (score 1):

Use a library such as [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (or one of many others available) to fetch the URL, and then store the result in an `std::string`.

Comment: I will appreciate if you can demonstrate some code as I havent used cURL before.

Comment: cURL is quite well documented. Look for the "easy" API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows then there is no need to use cURL library - try the api call [URLOpenBlockingStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127%28VS.85%29.aspx). It is not hard to use and will download the JSON response from the server. JSON can be thought of as XML - it is structurally similar although there are noticeable [syntactical differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). That said, it shouldn't be too hard to write a simple parser.